# How to define virtual method with return type which is not void in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

This might sound like a dumb question, but I need to write a virtual method that is being overridden by inherited class. I don't need the virtual method to have any code, since this method is fully dependent on inherited class, therefore all code will be in the override methods.

However, the method has a return type that is not void. If I keep the virtual method empty it would give me an error "no all path return a value".

The only solution I came up with was to implement the virtual method with returning a dummy empty string, but I don't feel this is the best way. Is there any other way to define a virtual method with return type?

**Edit:**

Even most answers were correct in their own way, they did not help in my case, therefore I am adding snippets of the code which shows why I need to create instance of the base class, and why I can't use interface, or abstract:

```
//base class
public class Parser
{
    public virtual string GetTitle()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

//sub class
public class XYZSite : Parser
{
    public override string GetTitle()
    {
        //do something
        return title;
    }
}

// in my code I am trying to create a dynamic object 
Parser siteObj = new Parser();
string site = "xyz";
switch (site)
{
    case "abc":
       feedUrl = "www.abc.com/rss";
       siteObj = new ABCSite();
       break;
    case "xyz":
       feedUrl = "www.xzy.com/rss";
       siteObj = new XYZSite();
       break;
}
//further work with siteObj, this is why I wanted to initialize it with base class, 
//therefore it won't break no matter what inherited class it was 
siteObj.GetTitle();
```

I know the way I cast Parser object to Site object doesn't seem very optimal, but this is the only way it worked for me, so Please feel free to correct any thing you find wrong in my code.

**Edit (Solution)**

I followed the advice of many of replies by using interface and abstract. However it only worked for me when I changed the base class to abstract along with all its methods, and inherited the base class from the interface, and then inherited the sub classes from the base class. That way only I could make sure that all classes have the same methods, which can help me generate variant object in runtime.

```
Public interface IParser
{
    string GetTitle();
}

Public abstract class Parser : IParser
{
    public abstract string GetTitle();
}

Public class XYZ : Parser
{
    public string GetTitle();
    {
        //actual get title code goes here
    }        
}

//in my web form I declare the object as follows
IParser siteObj = null;
...
//depending on a certain condition I cast the object to specific sub class
siteObj = new XYZ();
...
//only now I can use GetTitle method regardless of type of object
siteObj.GetTitle();
```

I am giving the credit to CarbineCoder since he was the one who put enough effort to take me the closest to the right solution. Yet I thank everyone for the contribution.

Comment: [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx)?

Comment: The super class itself is not abstract.

Comment: And yet it has a method that doesn't, in itself, do anything useful, and every overriding class should override? Doesn't it sound like it *ought* to be abstract?

Comment: I would really appreciate it fixing the logic of my code, I guess the source of the issue comes with the way I use inheritance in the first place. Please check the code above.

Comment: If `"abc"` and `"xyz"` are *exhaustive* (that is, no other `site` value is used) then just remove the `= new Parser()` part of the variable declaration and add a `default`  to your `switch` that throws `NotSupportedException` (to make the definite assignment analysis happy). Now the base class can be declared `abstract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since other answers have discussed about abstract/virtual implementation, I am suggesting my own version.

There is a contradiction in your requirement.

1. You want a base class which is not an abstract but it has a method which is not implemented. Don't you think this unimplemented method will make the class incomplete and end up making it an abstract one even though you haven't explicitly said so?
2. So lets assume your class will never be an abstract class and its perfectly reasonable to have it as a normal class. Does it make sense to remove this method from the class altogether and move it to an interface?

Can you try extracting this method and put it into an interface.

```
interface NewInterface
{
    string NewMethod();
}

public BaseClass
{
   ...
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass, NewInterface
{
    public string NewMethod
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

If you can do this, then you need not have to worry about the base class being abstract/ having NotImplemented exception, only downside is every derived class should implement this interface, but thats the point of making the base class non-abstract.

I don't see any problem in implementing Abstract BaseClass/ Interface for your approach. Both are supposed to be the solution for your problem.

```
//Parser siteObj = new Parser(); - Dont initialize it here, 
//your are initializing it once more below
NewIterface siteObj; 
string site = "xyz";
switch (site)
{
    case "abc":
       feedUrl = "www.abc.com/rss";
       siteObj = new ABCSite();
       break;
    case "xyz":
       feedUrl = "www.xzy.com/rss";
       siteObj = new XYZSite();
       break;
 }
```

Comment: This sounds good, but please check my update to see why I can't use interface.

Comment: I think you can use either abstract Class/ interface. They are ideally suited for creating an object at runtime :)

Answer (score 5):

You can throw NotImplementedException instead of returning object:

```
    public virtual object Method()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But if you are not implementing anything in virtual method you can create abstract instead of virtual:

```
    public abstract object Method();
```

Edit:

Another option is to create interface for it.

```
public interface IMethods
{
    object Method();
}
```

And make your classes children of this interface.

Comment: I can't define an abstract method in non-abstract class. Besides is it better to throw an exception than returning a dummy return?

Comment: So make it abstract or use virtual method as I wrote above. If your virtual method must be implemented then yes it's better to throw an exception.

Comment: That's interesting, why can you please tell me how is it better, I mean all I need is to get the sub class to call the overridden method, I would not need to handle the exception anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need but I wrote the options of what you can do.

Comment: Please check the code above, not sure if I can explain further.

Comment: In you example you **must** use abstract. Because your Parser class can't do anything alone. If you cannot initialize parser you can't use it. So there is no reason to create virtual method. 

Simply change Parser siteObj = null; and before you call siteObj.GetTitle(); check siteObj for null.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `abstract` here. The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation.

```
public abstract returntype MethodName();
```

**But** as you say, 'since this method is fully dependent on inherited class, therefore all code will be in the override methods', than if you are really going to override the functionality of the method in inherited class, why do you care if the method returns dummy or stuff? (e.g: you can make it virtual and get going)

**Edit**: as you cannot mark class as abstract, you can use `virtual` method instead.

```
public virtual returntype MethodName()
{
   .....
   return xyz;
}
```

(just for info: An `abstract` member is implicitly `virtual`.  and `abstract` is sort of `pure virtual`. so you need `virtual`, instead of `pure virtual`)

Comment: The overridden method has return type of string. So I need the virtual method to have the same return type. Yet I don't need the virtual method to any line of code.

Comment: @AbuLamar Exactly. you are rite now at a stage of compromising `x` for `y` or vice-verca. if you realy realy don't want any implementation, then according to priceiples, you should go for `abstract` class implementation. or you can compromise and return a dummy in your virtual method. After all, this is what virtual is for (i.e, to inform the compiler that if functionality is not overriden, please use virtual one). or other option is abstract ;)

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is that I am stuck in a situation where the super class is not abstract. I need to create an object out of it. Further more the super class has some methods that are not overridden. It just has some pure virtual methods that are being overridden. what I ended up is writing the method as follows: public virtual string GetTitle(){ return ""; } I just thought there would be a better way of handling this case.